# How to display all suggestions before typing anything in PyQt5 TableWidget?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pyqt5, qtablewidget

So i have a Item Completer class which i call in tableWidget.setItemDelegate, and when I write something in the tableWidget cell it starts to suggest it. But I want it to display all the things in the array so the user can chose from that.

```
self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(TableItemCompleter())

class TableItemCompleter(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(TableItemCompleter, self).__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, styleOption, index):
        editor = QLineEdit(parent)

        nevjegyzek_df = pd.read_csv(mypath+'/Adatok/nevjegyzek.csv',sep=';',encoding='utf-8')
        nevjegyzek_df = pd.DataFrame(nevjegyzek_df, columns=['Név'])
        completion_ls = list(nevjegyzek_df['Név'])
        autoComplete = QCompleter(completion_ls)
        editor.setCompleter(autoComplete)
        return editor
```

Comment: What about using an editable QComboBox instead of the QLineEdit?

Comment: @musicamante The cells are double-clickable, dont think that works with comboboxes

Comment: the doubleclick is only the edit trigger, and independent from the widget returned by `createEditor`. Have you tried it?